# Attempting to add an array as a Rails form input - how to get this to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to store a form input as an array in my database, but have yet to find a way to get it to work after a couple of hours searching.

The form contains a text field, with the intention that the user enter languages separated by commas. (So, for example, a user may type "French, German, Spanish".)

In my view this is represented as:

```
<%= f.label :languages_spoken, "Languages spoken" %>
<%= f.text_field :languages_spoken %>
```

The languages_spoken field is represented as a Postgres array in my database. Here's the relevant snipped of the migration that created it:

```
:languages_spoken, :string, array: true, default:
```

Upon entering any kind of value into the form, however, the result appears not to save into the database.

I expect there may be a problem with my strong_parameters, since in my output languages_spoken is being listed as an unpermitted parameter. I have been unable to figure out how to ensure the attribute is permitted, however.

Right now it's in my controller as the last permitted attribute, as follows:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, { languages_spoken: [] })
```

I've read of the above syntax working for others, but for me this still results in languages_spoken being listed as an unpermitted parameter.

Any ideas on how to proceed from here? I feel like I must be missing something obvious, but can't figure it out despite much searching. Open also to workarounds or entirely different ways to achieve the same objective.

**UPDATE**

I've arrived at a solution that works, but is far from elegant. I'll post here in case it benefits others facing a similar problem, but if anyone else has a neater solution - please do chime in.

The first comment below prompted me to try change my strong_parameters to

```
params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :languages_spoken)
```

This, as expected, did permit the languages_spoken attribute.

I added some fairly crude logic to my model to convert the text input into a format the database would accept as an array.

```
def languages_spoken=(value)
  language_to_input = "{" + value + "}"
  self[:languages_spoken] = language_to_input
end
```

And that seemed to do the trick such that a user's "Language 1, Language 2, Language 3" input can be saved as an array in the db.

Comment: What happens when you try  `params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :languages_spoken)` ?

Comment: An interesting question. When I tried that, the languages_spoken attribute was no longer an 'unpermitted attribute'. However, it did not insert any information into the database. I wonder if I need to ensure the user input is formatted correctly to be entered into the db as an array.

Comment: another option might be to just provide boxes named languages_spoken[], then when they get submitted rails *should* make it an array for you,  I've not tried though....